# Unexpected behaviour in copying directories from host to docker container from mac to docker linux in a dockerfile

Tags: python, docker

Hi I'm confused by the behaviour in a DockerFile. I've got a docker file and I

create a workdir and then I copy subdirectories from my host system (A mac osx) to a linux container based on AWS Lambda.

The pertinent lines are

```
WORKDIR /var/task
RUN mkdir -p /var/task/deploy/code
RUN mkdir -p /var/task/src
COPY ./deploy/code deploy/code/

COPY ./src src/
```

Which all run successfully, I can see from the logs that the copying completes. However when I log into the docker container with bash as an entrypoint.

I end up with no `deploy` or `src` container. I've experimented with various versions of this and I haven't found anything that works. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was running the wrong command. 
I needed to use `docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash integration` not `docker brun --rm -it -v "PWD":/var/task --entrypoint bash integration`